# Add HTML file in webBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm a newbie with this. Here is my problem:

I want to call a HTML file located in my PC clicking a button like this (I'm using c#).

```
private void Button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
 navegador.Navigate("C:/Users/aMan/Desktop/HelloWorld.html");
}
```

In which `navegador` is the name of the `webBrowser control`.

I was reading some notes that you answered before, even following the steps I can't get my `webBrowser` loads that file. So pretty please, with sugar on top, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, correct me if I am wrong but you need the directory to be double slashed in order for it to work.

```
Uri HTMLPath = new Uri("C://Users//aMan//Desktop//HelloWorld.html");
navegador.Navigate(HTMLPath);
```

How about that?

Comment: I tried and didn't work. When i use "navegador.Navigate('location her');" it says that must be a System.uri in the brackets, therefore i create an uri object:
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri page = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/aMan/Desktop/HelloWorld.html");
            navegador.Navigate(page);
        }

It runs with no problems until i click the button and sends an exception. Thank you!

Comment: Try my updated solution. And what is the exception? That way I can help.

Comment: I tried it again but didn't work. The same dubugger appears and doesn't let me go to the file. I'm wondering if there is another control in which I could open HTML easier. Thank you!

Comment: Here:

private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {                
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Just add an @ before the string like so.

```
navegador.Navigate(@"C:/Users/aMan/Desktop/HelloWorld.html");
```

Your basic command is correct. It is just the either the @ or // slashes are required in strings so that .NET does not treat single slashes (/) as escape characters.

Also, (and this is just a bonus), the WebBrowser control does not function well with modern browsers and is not the most optimal way to retrieve Web content for a page.

Comment: @ Anthony Yeah, this was my first line code but it didn't work. When I put the file location within the brackets it says 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.Navigate(System.Uri)' has no valid arguments. For that I created an Uri object with named "page". So I put "page" into the brackets and runs the app, but throws out an exception clicking the button. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net:

```
        Dim theFileHtml As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\test1.txt")
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("")
        Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Loop
        WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = theFileHtml 'Also You Can Use WebBrowser1.DocumentText
```

C#:

```
string theFileHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:\\test1.txt");
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("");
    while (WebBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
        Application.DoEvents();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
        //Also You Can Use WebBrowser1.DocumentText
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = theFileHtml;
```